# .NET Domain Model validation and Buddy Classes

Tags: entity-framework, validation, domain-driven-design

My domain model objects (generated by entity framework) have validation on it (using attributes and the IValidatableObject interface ) reading through the comments people seem to be against putting validation attributes in the domain model (buddy classes).

I am using specialized ViewModel classes with its own validation attributes to handle client side validation in the UI (ASP.NET MVC), I still need the validation attributes on the domain model as my business layer is exposed to other clients UIs, is this a good approach?

Comment: Seems like violation of DRY because you are creating validation twice on two different places just to satisfy needs of framework.

Comment: Thanks, What would be the best approach then? note that I need the validation on the domain model because I have other clients using the business layer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Its a good approach because your are doing validation on the server side. Your domain logic should not assume that the client validates (the client *should* of course validate). But besides from that, I would not validate a domain by attributes because validation rules are context-specific; they depend on the operation which you are performing. I put validation in the methods representing the different use-cases of the domain (the write operations) such as "create customer", "bill customer", "cancel order", etc. Don't assume that all your validation rules are invariants.

I don't see how you can reuse the server and client validation without exposing your domain entities outside of the boundaries of your service, which is a lot worse.